# Enviar valor checkbox não selecionado pelo formulário

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Tenho um formulario html, e nele eu tenho um input checkbox, eu preciso enviar o valor desse checkbox independente se esta selecionado ou nao, se tiver selecionado envia 1 se nao tiver envia 0. So que quando nao esta selecionado ele nao envia nada, argumento nenhum, so envia algum argumento. a url quando eu dou marco o checkbox. Alguem sabe dizer como eu consigo enviar o valor do checkbox nao marcado pela url tb?

```
<form method="get" action="paginadestino">
  <table class="tabelas" id="tabelaUsuarios2" bordercolor=green align="center" border="1px solid #ddd">
        <tr id="linhaParaClone" style="display:none">
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" style="width:120px" maxlength="20" required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="senha" style="width:95px" maxlength="20" required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="tag" style="width:80px" maxlength="8" required>
            </td>
            <td style="display:none">
                <input type="text" name="permissoes" style="width:80px" value="0-0-0-0-0" required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="time" name="hrentrada" style="width:80px" maxlength="4" required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="time" name="hrsaida" style="width:80px" maxlength="4" required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="adm">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="mais" onclick="clonarLinha()">+</button>
                <button type="button" name="menos" onclick="removeLinha(this)">-</button>
            </td>
            <td></td>
       </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor? O valor do checkbox é sempre 1? Se for sempre o mesmo valor, não faz sentido nem enviar no submit, basta já no backend colocar o valor 1 para a variável que representa o checkbox. Ou até mais, não faz nem sentido ter checkbox no formulário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qual a necessidade de enviar uma variável sem dado, se  valor não chegar vc já sabe que não foi clicado. É só no seu back-end verificar se está chegando alguma resposta.
Exemplo PHP:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_GET['adm'])){
    $admin = "Sim";
}else{
    $admin = "Não";
}
?>
```

EDIT 1:
Adição de Exemplo mas que não tem muita lógica existir.

```js
$("#enviar").click(function(){
  if($("#adm").is(':checked')){
   $("#valor_checkbox").val("Checado");
   $("#checkbox_show").val("Checado");
  }else{
   $("#valor_checkbox").val("DesChecado");
   $("#checkbox_show").val("DesChecado");   
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="adm" name="adm">
<input type="hidden" id="valor_checkbox" name="valor_checkbox">
<button id="enviar">Enviar</button></br></br>
<label>Input Demo</label>
<input type="text" id="checkbox_show" name="checkbox_show">
```

Explicação:

Você pode utilizar `JavaScript` para verificar se o checkbox está marcado quando você submeter o formulário. E utilizar o `if()` para preencher um campo oculto(`<input type='hidden'>`), para salvar uma string que representa quando o checkbox está marcado ou não.